# asp.net hidden fields - being modified?

Tags: asp.net

This is a clarification question: I'm studying for MCTS 70-515 and in my training kit it states that Hidden Fields: **"users can view or modify data stored in hidden fields"**

Now I'm aware that users can view the source of the page and then that would display the hidden field data.  But I'm curious as to the modification part.  How would a user modify a hidden field data and how would it affect the site?  Even if they modify the data via View Source they can't save the page and then post the data back to the server.

***What am I missing that the author is assuming I know?***

OK well all the answers said the same thing (at this time).  I guess if the author would of said "**savvy**" user then that might of tipped me off.  I guess I've always assumed that users wouldn't know of Firebug or any other tool that can do manipulation after the page has been displayed to the user.

Thank you for all your answers.  I appreciate it!

Comment: There are browser plugins that let you modify/set value of any input field. The change is on the client site but on next postback, the value would be updated on server site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hidden field is <strike>just a key-value-pair</strike> represented as a key-value-pair when serialized and sent to the server, just like any other form element. There are a number of ways to modify hidden fields - one is to use FireBug or some other "developer console" in the browser, another is to manually write the request and send it to the server.

Comment: `The hidden field is just a key-value-pair`, no, it's *used* as a key-value pair, it *is* an HTML `input` or `hidden` element and asp control that is populated from that value in a HTTP form from postbacks. You've also missed the most likely way in which a hidden would be changed in the wild, which is JavaScript.

Comment: @StuperUser You're correct - a hidden field is not a key-value pair. I've edited the post slightly.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change the value of a hidden field on the server during a postback, as you know, or on the client using JavaScript.

Example using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/JGsQ5/

Once the page has been loaded by the browser, it is stored in the DOM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) which is what JavaScript manipulates and is used by the browser to build a HTTP request which is sent back to the server as a postback.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using a debugging tool such as Firebug, the user could change the value of a hidden field indirectly though other interactions (with JavaScript) making the change for them. Normally, the user would be unaware of the technical detail of what they are doing (they neither know about, nor care about the fact a hidden field got changed)

Other tools, such as Fiddler, may intercept the web request and change the value of the hidden (or any) field as it is being transfered to the server on a postback.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, open up a program like `FireBug` and change the element value.  Remember, markup is client side, so the server is trusting the client to send back the right data -- however, this is easily circumvented.

It is best to store data that is essential to the security of your application in session's, whereas the data remains on the server side and is tied to the client.  ASP.NET can make up of hashes to prevent the unauthorized modification of fields, amoung other things.